# How to obtain the median for two variables

Tags: r, median

I have two variables (glycemy score1 and glycemie score2), it's the same variable but not at the same time and i want to combined these two variables to obtain only one median.

this is my data frame

```
ID  Glycemie score 1      Glycemie score 2
1   1.50                  5.56
2   1.82                  2.35
3   1.84                  1.65
4   3.51                  2.4
```

until 1000ID

so i'm looking for a code to match this two column to have the median please

Comment: You could just do `median(c(mydf$score1, mydf$score2))` but I'm not clear on what you mean by "match".

Comment: @Phil thank it's work, !  I was thinking of matching these two columns but you're right it's more simple like this

Comment: @mumber1 I would recommend you put your data into long form (e.g., using `pivot_longer` from `tidyr`) and have an additional column for `time` (1 or 2 in this example). This will make it easier to do most common analyses.